# Calling function by string not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I'm trying to write a js function that triggers another, variable, function when complete. I figured I could do this by passing the second function's name as a string, but I can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
logMeIn('likeThisPost');

function logMeIn(callBack) {
    //First function content
        $.post("/ajaxurl/",
            {   
                login_id: login_id,
                intent: 'login'             
            },
            function(){
                console.log('Logged in, refreshing header');
                $.post("/secondajaxurl/",{},
                    function(data){
                    //success
                        if(typeof callBack!=='undefined') {
                            window[callBack]();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            );      
        });
    }
```

This should, according to my thinking, run `likeThisPost` after successfully completing both ajax calls in `logMeIn`, but instead I get this error:

> window[callBack] is not a function

The function I'm calling on success definitley exists, and besides which, it doesn't look like it's even trying to call that function, but it's treating `callBack` as literal rather than a string.

I'm using jQuery and have everything wrapped in a $. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `I'm using jQuery and have everything wrapped in a $` that sounds like your problem. For `window[callback]()` to work, the function named in `callback` needs to be declared in global scope, not under a jquery document.ready handler. It would make far more sense to actually pass the function reference in anyway, instead of cobbling together the function name from the `window` reference.

Comment: `logMeIn(likeThisPost)` maybe?

Comment: Where did you declare the `function likeThisPost()`? This should work (I think) if you declared the function on the root and not inside any function like `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: I believe you created your `likeThisPost` function outside of window scope.

Comment: @JonasW. - I also had to call it directly rather than going through `window` (which was how I was directed to do it in every tutorial!).

Comment: You should definetly change your tutorial source. This is just ugly.

Comment: @JonasW. It was from StackOverflow! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Jonas W and  Rory McCrossan, the answer was to change the passed function to the function name, rather than a string, and then call the function directly rather than using `window`.

So `logMeIn(likeThisPost)` instead of `logMeIn("likeThisPost")` and `callBack();` rather than `window[callBack]();`.

Thanks!